# Series estimate

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

How the following series
$$1 - \sum_{j=2}^{n} \frac{(2-\eta)(\eta-1)}{  (j+\eta-3)(j+\eta-2) } = \frac{n(\eta-1)}{2-(2-\eta)}, \qquad \eta\neq 1,$$
has this form $\frac{n(\eta-1)}{2-(2-\eta)}$

Comment: As shown by user 108128, generally if denominator has linear factors which differ by constant, here by $1$, then there's a tendency of telescoping after splitting into partial fraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use fraction decomposition
\begin{align}
1 - \sum_{j=2}^{n} \frac{(2-\eta)(\eta-1)}{(j+\eta-3)(j+\eta-2)}
&= 1 - (2-\eta)(\eta-1)\sum_{j=2}^{n} \frac{1}{(j+\eta-3)(j+\eta-2)}\\
&= 1 - (2-\eta)(\eta-1)\sum_{j=2}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{j+\eta-3}-\frac{1}{j+\eta-2}\right)
\end{align}
and telescopic property on summation.

Comment: Thanks, it works.